# CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm using [AVCaptureSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to scan for QR codes in a Swift app. I'd like to draw a box around the detected QR code but I'm having trouble converting the "corners" property of [AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject/corners) into something usable.

> **var corners: [AnyObject]! { get }**
>
> The value of this property is an array of CFDictionary objects, each
>   of which has been created from a CGPoint struct using the
>   CGPointCreateDictionaryRepresentation function, representing the
>   coordinates of the corners of the object with respect to the image in
>   which it resides.

I've tried this (based on a [project by werner77](https://github.com/werner77/WECodeScanner/blob/master/WECodeScanner/WECodeScannerView.m)) but I get the following compiler error **"'CGPoint?' is not identical to 'CGPoint'"**

```
// MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let metadataObject = metadataObjects[0] as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject;
    var corners = metadataObject.corners as Array<NSDictionary>;
    var topLeftDict = corners[0] as NSDictionary;
    var topLeft : CGPoint?

    // COMPILE ERROR: 'CGPoint?' is not identical to 'CGPoint'
    CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation(topLeftDict, &topLeft)   
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Understand *optionals*.

Any type can have a `?` appended, which means that it can also be `nil`. The great thing about this is that you have to address or ignore `nil` objects explicitly, unlike in Objective-C where a `nil` object could lead to untraceable bugs.

When getting an object from a dictionary, it has to be optional because it is possible that the key is not present in the dictionary. `CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation` expects a non-optional, therefore you have to use an *initialized non-optional*.

```
// Playground:
var point = CGPointMake(1, 2)
var dictionary = CGPointCreateDictionaryRepresentation(point)
var aPoint = CGPointZero
CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation(dictionary, &aPoint)
aPoint // x 1, y 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<CGPoint>>`, but it wants an `UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>`.

```
var topLeft: CGPoint?
var point = CGPointZero
if CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation(topLeftDict, &point) {
    topLeft = point
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet :

```
    let corners = metadataObject.corners.map{(point)->CGPoint in
                let dict = point as! NSDictionary
                let x = dict["X"]!.doubleValue
                let y = dict["Y"]!.doubleValue

                return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            }
```